# How to validate JWT token from Google pub/sub push (No pem found for envelope)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api-nodejs-client

### Context

I'm following [Google's RTDNs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#create-sub) guide on enabling Real-Time Developer Notifications. I've successfully created the topic and subscription and have received the push notifications sent to the API that I have created. I would now like to authenticate and validate these messages. For that, I'm following [this guide on Authentication and Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push?authuser=3#authentication_and_authorization). Their developer documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push?authuser=3#validating_tokens) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/pubsub/app.js) has a seemingly useful example.

### The Issue

After following the resources outlined above, I get the following error:

```sh
Error: No pem found for envelope: {"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}
```

### Relevant Code

```js
const authClient = new OAuth2Client();
// ... 
app.post('/pubsub/authenticated-push', jsonBodyParser, async (req, res) => {

  // Verify that the push request originates from Cloud Pub/Sub.
  try {
    // Get the Cloud Pub/Sub-generated JWT in the "Authorization" header.
    const bearer = req.header('Authorization');
    const [, token] = bearer.match(/Bearer (.*)/);

    // Verify and decode the JWT.
    // Note: For high volume push requests, it would save some network
    // overhead if you verify the tokens offline by decoding them using
    // Google's Public Cert; caching already seen tokens works best when
    // a large volume of messages have prompted a single push server to
    // handle them, in which case they would all share the same token for
    // a limited time window.

    // verifyIdToken is failing here with the `No pem found for envelope` error
    const ticket = await authClient.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: 'example.com',
    });

    // ...

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid token');
    return;
  }

  res.status(200).send();
});
```

### The Questions

From this, I'm assuming I need to have some public key.

1. Where do I get said public key?
2. Where do I put said public key so that the google client is initialized with it?
3. How can I generate an example JWT to test my endpoint?

## Edits

I was able to find the source of this error in [their code here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L1220-L1223):

```js
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(certs, envelope.kid)) {
      // If this is not present, then there's no reason to attempt verification
      throw new Error('No pem found for envelope: ' + JSON.stringify(envelope));
    }
```

However, I've verified that the `kid` attribute does indeed exist in the decoded object:

```sh
{"alg":"RS256","kid":"7d680d8c70d44e947133cbd499ebc1a61c3d5abc","typ":"JWT"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the `kid` was invalid and therefore threw the `No pem found for envelope` error. Once a valid `kid` was supplied, the error no longer persisted.

Comment: In my case I was dealing with a very old token generated by Google. public/private keys of google has changed since the JWT token was generated, hence the signature (kid claim) was not valid anymore albeit the token's envelope was valid.